# How to set cronjob to send emails during an condition fails? and How to test it in local ubuntu system?

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.7, ubuntu-12.04

I need to perform a cronjob which sends emails when a perticulor condition fails. Cronjob should run everyday. And How to test the cronjob in local machine (I am using ubuntu 12.04).

I have already setup the sendmail for php. mails are going from magento.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to run PHP from a command line on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

The way to handle exceptions in PHP is

```
try {
} catch (Exception $e) {
  mail('test@example.com', 'Error subject of thing failed', "Body of thing failed\n".print_r($e,1));
}
```

If you want the script to stop once the error has occurred, just put a die() or exit after the mail() call.

But your question is a little light on details since we don't know what's failing or where.  It could just be that your PHP code is checking for X in the OS/filesystem, then all you need is to call mail() when the condition is found.

As far as the cronjob side goes you need to do this:

1. crontab -l > crontab.txt
2. Use editor of choice to open crontab.txt
3. Add a line at the bottom of crontab.txt (example below)
4. crontab crontab.txt
5. Then run crontab -l | less to review the new crontab to make sure it is correct

This will run every day at 1:45am server time

```
45 1 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/to/run.php
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Examples

You can test the script by running it manually or setting the cronjob to start in the near future instead of 1:45am

Comment: Thanks joefresco. Your answer helped me a lot.